# How to measure power consumption(mWh) on Nexus 6p?

Tags: android, nexus-6p

Here's [a link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jMuvRYWptZfP5zpvWmPJPRL-iowtgBVX45rSvew0VH4) that chromium developer says that Nexus 6p has integrated power usage meter.

> The measurement was done on a Nexus 6P, which has an integrated power usage meter.

How can I use it? Is there any standard android API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the API for the [BatteryManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html), which we use to do some power measuring on Nexus 6 phones.  Specifically look at `BATTERY_PROPERTY_ENERGY_COUNTER`, `BATTERY_PROPERTY_CHARGE_COUNTER`, and `BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW`.  Have fun!